# output two dataframes inside dplyr pipes

Tags: r, dplyr

Doing some computation and I've noticed that for further manipulation I'd need to preserve dataframe in a prior state.
So, I have a bunch of dplyr steps and in the middle of pipe chain I would like to preserve data frame state into other object

is this possible?

```
df <- read.csv(file) %>%
      mutate(....) %>%
      mutate(....) %>%
      # save df state to new df2 object here.......*****
      group_by(....) %>%
      arrange(var) %>%
      summary()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
df <- read.csv(file) %>%
  mutate(....) %>%
  mutate(....)

# save df state to new df2 object here.......*****
df2 <- df

df %>% group_by(....) %>%
  arrange(var) %>%
  summary()
```

Inside the pipe chain as requested:

```
df <- read.csv(file) %>%
  mutate(....) %>%
  mutate(....) %>%
  {df2 <<- .} %>% # save df state to new df2 object here.......*****
  group_by(....) %>%
  arrange(var) %>%
  summary()
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: this was my first approach but not "inside pipe" as requested